# htaccess model link add dot after domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Hello i'm create modification link with htaccess on my website. 
But i have a problem

this code htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$                                     page4.php?link=$1 [L]
```

I try type :

www.sampledomain.com/linkname

this work, i change value model link in database to "**link.name**"

but i try type :

www.sampledomain.com/link.name

**404 not found** :(

how to fix this ?
Help me thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex pattern and add couple of `RewriteCond`:

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ page4.php?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```